# How can I pull all remote changes with rebase instead of merge?

Tags: git, version-control, rebase, pull

I can pull changes using `git pull`, but it merges my local commits.  Is there a `git rebase` equivalent with which I can pull in remote changes?

Comment: Related: [How to make Git pull use rebase by default for all clones?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13846300/456814).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes you can `git pull --rebase`.

You can also set that to be the default pull behaviour when you track a branch with `git config branch.autosetuprebase always`. Replace "always" with "remote" or "local" if you want to do it to those specific types of branches that you're tracking.

Now all you have to do is `git pull`.

If for some reason you want to do a merge, you can do `git pull --no-rebase`.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE: see comments below for how to do this on existing branches.

Comment: `branch.autosetuprebase` only changes the default pull “mode” for *new* branches that have an upstream to track. `branch.<name>.rebase` is the variable that controls the operation for an individual branch (it is set to true for new “tracking” branches if `branch.autosetuprebase` is true when the branch is created). Use `git config branch.<name>.rebase true` to set it manually for a single branch.

Comment: correct. I forgot to mention the existing tracking branches. You can also edit the config by hand if you know what you're doing.

Comment: To do it be editting the config file, find the section for the branch and add:

    rebase = true

Comment: Also add a --global flag to apply it to the global git config and not just the repository: git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always

Comment: you can also set "rebase = True" in the [pull] section of your .gitconfig.

Comment: @dbw that's useful if you are already tracking branches and they are merging.

Comment: `git config branch.autosetuprebase always` will only rebase while updating the local tracking branch when doing `git pull` and otherwise do normal merges when merging from one branch to other. Is that correct understanding?

Comment: Also `git config --global pull.rebase true`

Answer (score 16):

Instead of `autosetuprebase`, you can use the `pull.rebase` config option to change the behavior for *every* `git pull` (instead of only newly-created branches):

```
[pull]
    rebase = true
```

The difference is this will apply to non-tracking branches and any branches you had set up before enabling `autosetuprebase`. So if you really want `pull --rebase` to always be the default, `pull.rebase` is the way to go!

Comment: @Bohdan true...I gave up on TortoiseGit for every day use a long time ago, if you want to do anything tricky with git you end up having to go to the command line anyway.

Answer (score 6):

I usually use a fetch/rebase combination so my current (local) work stays at the top:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/develop
```

Answer (score 2):

To change default behavior from `merge` to `rebase` In git >= 1.7.9:

`git config --global pull.rebase true`

remove global if you want to apply for current repo only