# How can I deal with this Git warning? "Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is discouraged"

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-config, fast-forward

After a `git pull origin master`, I get the following message:

```
warning: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
commands sometime before your next pull:

  git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
  git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
  git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only

You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
invocation.

remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), 51.49 KiB | 850.00 KiB/s, done.
```

The pull seems successful, but I am unsure.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: File a bug report that the warning is confusing. One option should be "recommended" and the warning should only show on request and not just because a version change happened. Lot's of automatic scripts might break now with  this unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl, the warning shouldn't affect any scripts as it continues to retain the default behaviour until explicitly changed. It shouldn't cause the pull to return a non-zero exit code (given it's a warning, not an error). A few CI/CD scripts that I have deployed accross various servers continue to work with the success rate unaffected.

Comment: @Qumber - thanks for the comment. Crontab entries will e.g. start sending e-mail if output appears that wasn't there or could be filtered with a simple grep. Unexpected output can have all kinds of side effects.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl, Every pull usually has some different output. So, any script that depends solely on that is probably badly written. Also, one should not upgrade a production environment without extensive testing. I prefer to not upgrade prod at all. Instead, I create a new instance with latest everything, host my apps there, test everything out, and then make it production.

Comment: I got this message and weirdly enough it seems that it was caused by VS Code. When I entered `git push` in the terminal, my code was pushed without a problem.

Comment: Like @MikhailRatner, I used `git push` in the terminal without any issues. If someone faces this problem in the VS Code, I recommend trying this solution.

Comment: Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71768999/how-to-merge-when-you-get-error-hint-you-have-divergent-branches-and-need-to-s

Comment: In my case [I resolved it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75893425/5626568) just using: `git pull --no-ff`

Comment: The comments here and at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71768999/how-to-merge-when-you-get-error-hint-you-have-divergent-branches-and-need-to-s suggest that git's output simply isn't up to the job of communicating with its users about what the problem is.  "File a bug report" might actually be the right answer, if anything good would come of it.  Though long, https://stackoverflow.com/a/71774640/8145448 is actually the best explanation.

Comment: I get the same problem frequently, and have a real problem solving it.  I am the only one who has ever cloned the repo, and I am the only one who has ever pushed, and only from one dir. But I always get this error, and the recommended "fix" "git config pull.ff only" gives "fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting." leaving me more confused than before.

Answer (score 1167, accepted):

> In its default mode, git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD.

When you do a `git pull origin master`, 
`git pull` performs a merge, which often creates a merge commit. Therefore, by default, pulling from the remote is *not* a harmless operation: it can create a new commit SHA hash value that didn’t exist before. This behavior can confuse a user, because what feels like it should be a harmless download operation actually changes the commit history in unpredictable ways.

To avoid this, you need

```
git pull --ff-only
```

(or not? read on to see which one fits your requirements)

With `git pull --ff-only`, Git will update your branch only if it can be “fast-forwarded” without creating new commits. If this can’t be done, `git pull --ff-only` simply aborts with an error message.

You can configure your Git client to always use `--ff-only` by default, so you get this behavior even if you forget the command-line flag:

```
git config --global pull.ff only
```

Note: The `--global` flag applies the change for all repositories on your machine. If you want this behaviour only for the repository you're in, omit the flag.

Taken from [here](https://blog.sffc.xyz/post/185195398930/why-you-should-use-git-pull-ff-only)

---

This warning was added in Git 2.27.

This is what the complete warning looks like:

> Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
> discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
> commands sometime before your next pull: 
>  
> git config pull.rebase false     # merge (the default strategy) 
> git config pull.rebase true      # rebase 
> git config pull.ff only                # fast-forward only 
>  
> You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
> preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
> or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
> invocation.

The warning presents three commands as options, all of these will suppress the warning. But they serve different purposes:

```
git config pull.rebase false     # merge (the default strategy)
```

This keeps the default behaviour and suppresses the warning.

```
git config pull.rebase true      # rebase
```

This actually commits on top of the remote branch, maintaining a single branch both locally and remotely (unlike the default behaviour where two different branches are involved - one on local and the other on remote - and, to combine the two, a merge is performed).

```
git config pull.ff only          # fast-forward only
```

This only performs the pull if the local branch can be fast-forwarded. If not, it simply aborts with an error message (and does not create any commits).

---

**Update 1:**

If you have Git 2.29 or above, you can now set `pull.ff` to `false`, `true` or `only` to get rid of the warning.

```
git config pull.ff true
```

`true` - This is the default behaviour. Pull is fast-forwarded if possible, otherwise it's merged.

```
git config pull.ff false
```

`false` - Pull is never fast-forwarded, and a merge is always created.

```
git config pull.ff only
```

`only` - Pull is fast-forwarded if possible, otherwise operation is aborted with an error message.

---

**Update 2:** 
There was a bug in this newly implemented feature until version `2.35` where Git would show this warning even if the user passed one of the three flags with the `git pull` command. This has now been fixed, consider updating your Git to version `2.36` or above.

---

**Notes:**

- Read [this very well written answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71774640/10625611) by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) to get a much clearer picture on what actually happens behind the scene and to understand which option is the most appropriate option for you.
- You may want to keep an eye on [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64163084/10625611) for updates on changes made to this feature in future updates.

Comment: As [commented on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62653114/how-to-deal-with-this-git-warning-pulling-without-specifying-how-to-reconcile/62653694#comment111756400_62653694), the warning is not affected by whether or not the branch is *actually* diverging. The initial "Your branch is probably diverging." may be misleading.

Comment: @Joe, true. Removed.

Comment: I have to say, the three options in the message did *not* work for me to supress the message. However the answer here (`git config --global pull.ff only`) _did_.

Comment: None of these options are great. `pull.ff true` is much more convenient than `pull.ff only` - it fast-forwards when it can, and merges when it can't, which produces less redundant merge commits than `pull.rebase false`. Is there another way to suppress the message while maintaining the `pull.ff true` behaviour?

Comment: @DiskJunky pay close attention to the next sentence after the 3 options: "You can replace `git config` with `git config --global` to set a default preference for all repositories."

Comment: I believe `pull.rebase false` is the default behaviour. Also `--pull.ff` works out of the box if you don't change it. Setting `pull.rebase false` will preserve the default behaviour where pull is fast-forwarded if possible, and merged when not. See [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullff) & [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---ff)

Comment: Aha! Thanks @Qumber. I had already tried `pull.rebase false`, but it wasn't working as described. It was **always** creating a merge commit, and *never* fast-forwarding. The root cause was that I had the `merge.ff false` setting. After clearing that setting, it fast-forwards when it should. Docs [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---ff) (almost identical to the [git pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---ff) docs)

Comment: I had to explicitly do `git config pull.ff true` for it to take.

Comment: Worth to mention that while pull.rebase true is amazing option, you won't be able to pull if you have unstashed changes. git pull
error: cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
error: additionally, your index contains uncommitted changes.
error: please commit or stash them. etc.

Comment: @KamilDziedzic That's because Git does not let you pull with rebase if your index is not clean. One option is to autostash your changes while rebasing - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43262939/10625611

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Helped a lot. I am working only with feature branches. On my develop there are no local changes. Therefore the default will do pretty well for me. But if I used pull.ff and have a conflict, how would I get that problem and what would I do if ff is not possible?

Comment: This is a really good explanation. I've actually run into this unexpected behavior when pulling before. For me, it happened when I used `git pull origin main` to update the main branch while I was still on a feature branch locally (I forgot to checkout to the main branch locally first). It ended up pulling the remote main changes and also merging them into my feature branch. ff seems like a safer strategy.

Comment: What does "fast-forward" mean here?

Comment: @Victor Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29673993/10625611).

Comment: As simple answer has been overcomplicated to confuse you more lol

Comment: Does anything need to be done when say, you set it to fastforward only, but then a merge is required on a pull?

Comment: @Chucky, you can do a `git pull --merge` if you want to pull using merge. Or `git pull --rebase` to pull using rebase.

Comment: Which option was the default behavior in older versions of git from before this warning started showing? I am accustomed to how git pull operated in the past and would like to keep it the same if possible. 

pull.rebase false  mentions that it is the default behavior currently but not whether it was also the default behavior in the past. Was this also the default behavior in prior versions?

Comment: @FoamyGuy, the default strategy has been `merge` (`pull.rebase false`) since _version 1.x_. And continues to be the same. [This doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull/2.1.4) for _version 2.1.4_ (released 2014) explains the behaviour `"...git pull runs git fetch with the given parameters and calls git merge to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current branch."`.

Comment: This comment is helpful, the warning message says default is `pull.rebase false` but at least in my experience so far, the default strategy has been `pull.ff only`

Comment: Time to go back to TFS. git is way too complicated for my enterprise needs.

Comment: Perhaps this would be clearer if it was explained somewhere what a divergent branch even is. If I add a build pipeline file in Azure, and change a line of text in an unrelated area in my checked out repo I get the `divergent branches` error, but it seems to me that that situation is not even a file conflict. So what is the actual problem?

Comment: This works for me: `git config pull.ff true`

Answer (score 234):

This is a new warning [added](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d18c950a69f3a24e1e3add3d9fc427641f53e12b) in [Git 2.27](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a08a83db2bf27f015bec9a435f6d73e223c21c5e/Documentation/RelNotes/2.27.0.txt#L22):

```
 * "git pull" issues a warning message until the pull.rebase
   configuration variable is explicitly given, which some existing
   users may find annoying---those who prefer not to rebase need to
   set the variable to false to squelch the warning.
```

To remove the warning, set one of the suggested values to your preferred default behaviour for `git pull` if you don't specify behaviour on the command line (using `--ff`, `--no-ff`, `--ff-only`, `--rebase`). In all cases, `git` will attempt a fast-forward ([What is git fast-forwarding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673869/what-is-git-fast-forwarding)) merge if possible. The settings control what happens when there are changes in your branch but *not* present in the remote branch.

```
  git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
```

This is the existing default behaviour; set this for no warning, and no change in behaviour; `git` will merge the remote branch into your local one.

```
  git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
```

Here, `git` will attempt to rebase your changes on top of the remote branch. See [When should I use git pull --rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472254/when-should-i-use-git-pull-rebase) for more detail on why you might want that.

```
  git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
```

If a fast-forward merge is not possible, `git` will refuse to proceed. As [Difference between git pull --rebase and git pull --ff-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430600/difference-between-git-pull-rebase-and-git-pull-ff-only) quotes:

> Refuse to merge and exit with a non-zero status unless the current HEAD is already up-to-date or the merge can be resolved as a fast-forward

Comment: This is actually the most correct answer, because it explains why people (like me) are suddenly seeing this warning after nearly a decade of using git. However,it would be useful if some guidance were given on the options offered. for example, pointing out that setting pull.ff to "only" doesn't prevent you doing a "pull --rebase" to override it.

Comment: What's the difference between `pull.rebase = true` and `branch.autoSetupRebase = always` ?

Comment: @tekumara see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15935584/733345

Comment: "when there are changes in your branch but not present in the remote branch." Then it seems to me that git should only throw this warning *if that is the case.* If I'm pulling my mainline (and the mainline is used properly) I shouldn't need to worry about that.

Comment: @KeithTyler that's reasonable, but, as this warning is only logged and doesn't cause the command to fail, that could mean you only see it *after* your history has been changed in a way you don't expect. The intent is for you make a decision upfront.

Comment: @Joe I like your answer, and think it's the _right_ answer, but you see this regardless of whether git has actually _done_ anything.  I feel that the right time to issue this warning is if git has to _do_ something, then should fail with this message.  Not just spam users with this message upfront.  Yet another thing that contributes to my love/hate relationship with git.

Comment: Joe, thanks for your answer, it helps a lot. I'm not sure I understand what the ff-only flag is about. If `git pull` fails because ff-only is enabled, then what? At that point one must do a merge or rebase by hand in order to make any progress. So if the goal is to avoid messy dependency graphs, this doesn't change anything -- one way or another, automatically or by hand, your dependency graph will end up a mess. I suppose that if you have to do it by hand, you have more control over it. However I'm guessing that usually people won't know how to avoid a mess any more than the Git itself does.

Comment: This command alone worked for me: **git config pull.rebase false**

Answer (score 101):

`git pull origin main --rebase`

worked for me!

Comment: Same here. If you just had a commit on origin but forget to pull before commiting something else locally, but got no conflicts, this one (a simple rebase) will solve it for you.

Comment: I agree with https://stackoverflow.com/users/8991247/caique-c-pereira.

Comment: I have a lot of conflicts after that :(

Comment: this is the way, you are not modifying the other new commits from remote. And the world doesn't need to know about your local commits so feel free to modify and change its hash.
@VitalyZdanevich of course you can have merge conflict, you have to deal with it with or without rebase anyway. What do you expect?

Answer (score 92):

Run this:

```
git config pull.ff only
```

and congratulate yourself that you can get on with your work.

Comment: `fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.`

Comment: @y_159 Maybe is too late for you but it can be useful to someone else. To solve the `fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting` warning I used `git pull origin <branch> --rebase`. 
I have also noticed I didn't have the upstream set so in the first push I added that (`-u`) e.g. `git push -u origin <branch>`.

Comment: @ViníciusCerqueiraBonifácio I usually get this error, I ended up doing `git pull --no-ff`. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: This doesn't explain what it  does, and will only cause more problems down the line, when ff is not possible and the inexperienced user will be at loss on what to do -- additionally, with a non-default behaviour which will be harder to debug.

Comment: `git config pull.ff only` worked for me; required `git pull` before I could resume a push.

Comment: I get the same problem: fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.  This whole thing is a mystery: i am the only one who has ever cloned the repo, and the only one who has ever pushed to it, and only from one dir.  What on earth is going on?

Answer (score 55):

If one is using Git with Visual Studio (2019 or 2022) and started experiencing this issue, then you can define this option from the Git Tab -> Settings.

> Rebase local branch when pulling

Set as false if you want the branch to 'merge' changes and True if you want to 'rebase' the changes.

[image: VS 2019 - Git]

Comment: This did work for me on Visual Studio Enterprise 2022.

Answer (score 50):

It works for me

```
git config --global pull.ff true
```

Comment: This worked for me, while other solutions (event the most upvoted) gave me errors. Thank you.

Comment: this is the best answer so far.

Comment: I get "fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting"

Comment: try it `git pull --no-ff`

Answer (score 37):

There are already few good answers mentioned above but if you find it confusing you can try this out (warning: if you have local changes the following command will wipe the changes):

```
git reset --hard origin/<remote_branch_name>
```

Example: if your branch name is **master**

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This command will discard any of your local branch changes and make your local branch exactly same as your remote brach. In another word, it makes your local branch a carbon copy of your remote branch.

Comment: Don't do this unless you know what you're doing. You may end up losing your local work!

Comment: @Martino, you are right but this is clearly mentioned in the post that this will discard any local changes and make a fresh carbon copy as the remote....

Comment: I got `git reset --hard origin/dev
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/dev': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Answer (score 36):

`git config pull.ff only` or equivalently `git pull --ff-only` is the safest one. The reason is that a rebase can overwrite the history and may  cause the loss of commits if another developer has force-pushed to the same branch.

But all of them are valid.

Comment: How would that 'loss of commits' happen, actually?

Comment: "Loss of commits" does not happen. But if there are reverts and re-reverts it may choose the "in" or "out" for that change that you don't want. So it looks like it loses the revert, or the re-revert. Also if you're in the habit of commenting out old code a change may be applied to the commented out copy rather than the copy you want. FF-only doesn't do any of this patching so it's boring and safe.

Comment: Doesnt work for me. fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.  This is with the simplest possible repository, with only 1 main branch, and 2 people.  Its unfortunately two people (Who are not git experts) editing different files at the same time is such a problem for git.

Answer (score 31):

Note: Earlier we taught "[`git pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/299deeac8a67ef80989b86a75b012be1d2193bf9/Documentation/git-pull.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))</sup> to warn when the user does not say the histories need to be merged, rebased or accepts only fast-forwarding, but the warning triggered for those who have set the `pull.ff` configuration variable.

This is no longer the case (meaning: **no more warning**) with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020).

See [commit 54200ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54200cef86a67ea6666d02be7f21e66d471624bf) (24 Sep 2020) by [Alex Henrie (`alexhenrie`)](https://github.com/alexhenrie).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 299deea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/299deeac8a67ef80989b86a75b012be1d2193bf9), 29 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`pull`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54200cef86a67ea6666d02be7f21e66d471624bf): don't warn if `pull.ff` has been set
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alex Henrie</sup>

> A user who understands enough to set `pull.ff` does not need additional instructions.

---

Before Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), when a user does not tell "[`git pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d3fa84d52873cdf3852e41b684ab93475fe4424f/Documentation/git-pull.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))</sup> to use rebase or merge, the command gives a loud message telling a user to choose between rebase or merge but creates a merge anyway, forcing users who would want to rebase to redo the operation.

> Fix an early part of this problem by tightening the condition to give the message--- there is no reason to stop or force the user to choose between rebase or merge if the history fast-forwards.

See [commit 7539fdc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7539fdc6290750c617c0b638c2f3b2f63c389ed3), [commit b044db9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b044db9172f020768e85835f87bfc5564e310714) (14 Dec 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit c525de3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c525de335e4a3919d49a9126b76d1288f35737be), [commit 278f4be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/278f4be806f93579c64cd9993fdad2eb589f86c6), [commit 77a7ec6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77a7ec632952ee335cb544fee7c6b3fb1c5ec147) (12 Dec 2020) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d3fa84d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3fa84d52873cdf3852e41b684ab93475fe4424f), 06 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pull`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c525de335e4a3919d49a9126b76d1288f35737be): display default warning only when non-ff
>
> <sup>Suggestions-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Felipe Contreras</sup>

> There's no need to display the annoying warning on every pull... only the ones that are not fast-forward.
>
> The current warning tests still pass, but not because of the arguments or the configuration, but because they are all fast-forward.
>
> We need to test non-fast-forward situations now.

---

The warning changes with With 2.34 (Q4 2021): "[`git pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7d0daf3f12f87799a3b3f524933ef6c15d1f28c3/Documentation/git-pull.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))</sup> had various corner cases that were not well thought out around its `--rebase` backend, e.g. "[`git pull --ff-only`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7d0daf3f12f87799a3b3f524933ef6c15d1f28c3/Documentation/merge-options.txt#L48)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---ff-only))</sup> did not stop but went ahead and rebased when the history on other side is not a descendant of our history.

See also below: Git 2.34 does not yet fix everything.

See [commit 6f843a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f843a3355ee590dfe09eb90679051e75fadf675), [commit 359ff69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/359ff6938990a438b99e95fe36b6b359f3eb9811), [commit 031e2f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/031e2f7ae195069d00d21cde906fce5b0318dbdd), [commit adc27d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/adc27d6a9374d012b091bc348c20f5bfdbee52d1), [commit e4dc25e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4dc25ed49d94c93b1d3f63efe17f32ca682cab7) (22 Jul 2021), and [commit 1d25e5b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d25e5bdf5263a227d233eafcf028b36c72716f6), [commit be19c5c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be19c5ca3e28cb16d55623de2e5aa1d45bd5b5ba) (21 Jul 2021) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
See [commit 3d5fc24](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d5fc24daefbdf56bc36a491aed0b7990fa0c62f) (21 Jul 2021) by [Alex Henrie (`alexhenrie`)](https://github.com/alexhenrie).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7d0daf3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d0daf3f12f87799a3b3f524933ef6c15d1f28c3), 30 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pull`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/031e2f7ae195069d00d21cde906fce5b0318dbdd): abort by default when fast-forwarding is not possible
>
> <sup>Initial-patch-by: Alex Henrie</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> We have for some time shown a long warning when the user does not specify how to reconcile divergent branches with `git pull`.
> Make it an error now.

`git pull` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/031e2f7ae195069d00d21cde906fce5b0318dbdd/Documentation/git-pull.txt#L18-L29):

> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch.
>
> - If the current branch is behind the remote, then by default it will
>   fast-forward the current branch to match the remote.
> - If the current branch and the remote have diverged, the user needs to specify how to reconcile the divergent branches with `--no-ff`, `--ff`, or `--rebase` (or the corresponding configuration options in `pull.ff` or `pull.rebase`).
>
> More precisely, `git pull` runs `git fetch` with the given parameters and then depending on configuration options or command line flags, will call either `git merge` or `git rebase` to reconcile diverging branches.

So: instead of seeing (before Git 2.33.1):

> Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is discouraged.
> You can squelch this message by running one of the following commands sometime before your next pull:
>
> ```
> git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
> git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
> ```

You will see:

> You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
> You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before your next pull:
>
> ```
> git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
> git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
> ```

Meaning, if you *don't* run one of those commands, you will get a fatal error:

> ```
> fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
> ```

---

Update for Git 2.35 (Q1 2022)

[Ark Kun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1497385/ark-kun) reports:

> Git 2.34 is still broken. It refuses to pull a remote branch which is an ancestor of the current branch head.
> git fails instead of doing nothing.
> VSCode has sync feature that does pull and push.
> The feature has been broken for months because GIT changed the behavior.
>
> Fortunately this issue is finally fixed in GIT master

That was reported/discussed in this [Git mailing thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CADL96rvRX2R_4Wm23tz88hDUztcpK531RU+Ops2UVoiOW0bCHw@mail.gmail.com/T/#u), and a fix is in progress ([git commit ea1954a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea1954af771253660cd84dc73b8f2832327c9c02#diff-0e7db391c63d3bfd3f16472a3137dadf0281a91ae0de4c6eb95cb984230b9335))

Before Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), "[`git pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0f2140f105ded522ebfd784ae3e7f0885302513f/Documentation/git-pull.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))</sup> with any strategy when the other side is behind us should succeed as it is a no-op, but doesn't.

See [commit ea1954a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea1954af771253660cd84dc73b8f2832327c9c02) (17 Nov 2021) by [Erwin Villejo (`erwinv`)](https://github.com/erwinv).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0f2140f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f2140f105ded522ebfd784ae3e7f0885302513f), 21 Nov 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pull`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea1954af771253660cd84dc73b8f2832327c9c02): should be noop when already-up-to-date
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Erwin Villejo</sup>

> The already-up-to-date pull bug was fixed for `--ff-only` but it did not include the case where `--ff` or `--ff-only` are not specified.
>
> This updates the `--ff-only` fix to include the case where `--ff` or `--ff-only` are not specified in command line flags or config.

---

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), after "[`git pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9de14c71f720b1da50c95309fc06d30c8455aae2/Documentation/git-pull.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))</sup> that is configured with `pull.rebase=false merge.ff=only` fails due to our end having our own development, give advice messages to get out of the "`Not possible to fast-forward`" state.

See [commit 765071a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/765071a8f27fcaae27ce940b3a784b9d586faa12) (07 Mar 2023) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9de14c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9de14c71f720b1da50c95309fc06d30c8455aae2), 19 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`advice`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/765071a8f27fcaae27ce940b3a784b9d586faa12): add diverging advice for novices
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Felipe Contreras</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> The user might not necessarily know why ff only was configured, maybe an admin did it, or the installer (Git for Windows), or perhaps they just followed some online advice.
>
> This can happen not only on `pull.ff=only`, but `merge.ff=only` too.
>
> Even worse if the user has configured `pull.rebase=false` and `merge.ff=only`, because in those cases a diverging merge will constantly keep failing.
> There's no trivial way to get out of this other than [`git merge --no-ff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/765071a8f27fcaae27ce940b3a784b9d586faa12/Documentation/merge-options.txt#L47)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---no-ff))</sup>.
>
> Let's not assume our users are experts in git who completely understand all their configurations.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/765071a8f27fcaae27ce940b3a784b9d586faa12/Documentation/config/advice.txt#L139-L140):

> ### `diverging`
>
> Advice shown when a fast-forward is not possible.

So, instead of just seeing:

```
Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

You will see:

```
Diverging branches can't be fast-forwarded, you need to either:

  git merge --no-ff

or:

  git rebase

Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

Comment: In my case, I'm unable to do ff  with git pull after setting git config to ff only. what should I do now? git version - 2.33.1.

Comment: @y_159 It would be best to ask a new question detailing your situation in details, for me (and others) to suggests options/solutions.

Comment: Git 2.34 is still broken. It refuses to pull a remote branch which is an ancestor of the current branch head.

Comment: @Ark-kun But if the remote branch is an ancestor (meaning included in) of your current local branch, there would be nothing to pull, would it?

Comment: >there would be nothing to pull, would it? - Yes. But git fails instead of doing nothing. VSCode has sync feature that does pull and push. The feature has been broken for months because GIT changed the behavior. Fortunately this issue is finally fixed in GIT master. Waiting for release...

Comment: @Ark-kun Interesting. Do you have an issue or pull-request reference for that fix?

Comment: https://lore.kernel.org/git/CADL96rvRX2R_4Wm23tz88hDUztcpK531RU+Ops2UVoiOW0bCHw@mail.gmail.com/ https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea1954af771253660cd84dc73b8f2832327c9c02#diff-0e7db391c63d3bfd3f16472a3137dadf0281a91ae0de4c6eb95cb984230b9335

Comment: @Ark-kun Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment and the relevant references in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 26):

Try this answer-

You can use 'git config pull.rebase false' command to switch back to default merging strategy instead of using rebasing

```
git config pull.rebase false
```

Then use your pull command

```
git pull origin <Your branch name>
```

Answer from...

[https://www.cyberithub.com/solved-fatal-need-to-specify-how-to-reconcile-divergent-branches/#:~:text=Solution%201%3A%20Switch%20to%20Merge%20Strategy&text=You%20can%20use%20git%20config,instead%20of%20using%20rebasing%20strategy.&text=After%20switching%20back%20to%20default,the%20changes%20from%20main%20branch](https://www.cyberithub.com/solved-fatal-need-to-specify-how-to-reconcile-divergent-branches/#:%7E:text=Solution%201%3A%20Switch%20to%20Merge%20Strategy&text=You%20can%20use%20git%20config,instead%20of%20using%20rebasing%20strategy.&text=After%20switching%20back%20to%20default,the%20changes%20from%20main%20branch).

Comment: Thanks alot it was bothering me since long,

Answer (score 13):

git config pull.rebase false

## merge (the default strategy)

Answer (score 12):

In my case I just simply did this by :

```
git pull --rebase
```

I was able to get all the remote changes on my local branch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

**The default merging process instead of using rebasing**

```
git config pull.rebase false
```

**then**

```
git pull origin <branch name>
```

Answer (score 7):

Lets example you created one branch A from develop branch and during pull from develop to A branch getting this divergent issue. you unable to took update code from develop to ur A branch. so follow this steps to fix this issue

1. **git checkout develop-branch (this will switch to develop brnach)**
2. **git pull (it will pull all changes to develop)**
3. **git checkout A-feature-branch ( this will switch to your feature branch)**
4. **git merge develop-branch (it will merge all change to your feature branch)**

Now, you have updated code from develop to your local branch .
Enjoy your coding :)

Answer (score 7):

In my case I resolved it just using:

```
git pull --no-ff
```

Comment: What will happen exactly if we use this command. It's working for me but don't know how it will work.

Comment: [What does `--no-ff` for `git merge`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069061/what-effect-does-the-no-ff-flag-have-for-git-merge) The --no-ff flag prevents git merge from executing a "fast-forward" if it detects that your current HEAD is an ancestor of the commit you're trying to merge.

Answer (score 7):

These are hints from Git. It's suggesting that you configure your preferred behavir for the git pull command. Here's how you can configure it:

**Merge (Default Behavir):**
If you want to perform a merge when pulling changs, you can configure Git like this:

```
git config pull.rebase false
```

This will make git pull perform a merge by default.

**Rebase:**
If you prefer to rebase your changes on top of the incoming changes, you can configure Git like this:

```
git config pull.rebase true
```

Rebase moves your local commits on top of the incoming commits from the remote branch, creating a linear history.

**Fast-Forward Only:**
If you want to ensure that your branch only fast-forwards (i.e., updates without creating merge or rebase commits), you can configure Git like this:

```
git config pull.ff only
```

This will allow git pull to fast-forward your branch if possible; otherwise, it will reject the pull if it would result in a merge or rebase.

Comment: did you use any generative AI like chatgpt at all in the writing of any part of this answer?

Answer (score 5):

**The issue will be resolved with below command**

`git config --global  pull.ff true` run this command in your project directory terminal.

This is a ideal solution for this through Desktop, but in the mean time. For those unfamiliar with using the Command Line Interface (CLI).

> From **GitHub Desktop**, you can press Ctrl + ` (Also available from
> the "Repository" main menu as "Open in [Your set terminal]"). This
> should open up a CLI.
>
> From **SourceTree** -> Actions -> Open in Terminal. This will open
> Terminal with your project directory.
> [image: Open terminal using SourceTree]

In Terminal just type:
`git config --global  pull.ff true` (or any of the other options specified in the error hints).

Now when you attempt to pull it will use that configuration and allow you to continue.

I suggested `pull.ff true` simply because it attempts to fast forward your branch to be up to date with your remote before applying your local commits and if not it will perform a merge from the remote to your local branch. [Read docs here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).

Typically when you pull a branch, add commits, and push. It is in the order assuming your local is up to date with remote. By merging when fast forwarding is not possible, you will see a merge commit informing you of how it was handled. (The other options are to rebase or always merge, many new users find rebase to be less intuitive, but really accomplishes the same thing)

I added the `--global` flag so that your choice will apply to all your repos and you won't see this error message again. Simply omit this if you want a different behaviour for each repository.

Answer (score 5):

This command did the trick

```
git pull --rebase
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/<branch>
```

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you perform a `git pull` operation from the remote host, git will essentially merge remote into your local branch.

The error indicates that your local branch has diverged from the upstream remote branch. For example, this may happen whenever you rebase the remote branch (e.g. from GitHub UI), and at the same time you have attempted to push new changes from your local branch without first pulling the changes from the remote host.

---

The following command should help you resolve the error:

```
git pull origin <branch-name> --rebase
```

and you should now be able to `git push` from local to remote

Answer (score 3):

The safest option is set ff only globally. run:

```
git config --global pull.ff only
```

This option will be added to your global `.gitconfig`.

```
[pull]
    ff = only
```

If the fast-forward later is failing, try `git pull --no-ff`.

Answer (score 3):

This worked in my case:

> git rebase origin/my_remote_branch_name

Answer (score 3):

```
git pull origin --rebase
```

worked for me! I was trying to get manually uploaded files to project folder.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in 2.34.1 update your Git version.

Comment: 2.35 will be more robust. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64163084/6309). It will be released next week.

Answer (score 1):

Wow lots of good answers here.
But I want to answer from a route cause perspective...

Not easy to determine the OP **Route Cause** each person could be different.
Fixing issues is great but preventing them in the first place is even better.
although I respect the answer above because their knowledge is far greater than mine.

**Here is the Cause of my Issue same error as above:**

1. Doing a Commit and Push Pull from my Dev Branch to my remote Dev Branch (using VS Code);
2. Then a PR to my Team Branch.
3. then within github I merged my Team Branch into my Dev Branch (higher) to bring Dev up to level with other teams to ensure we all align.
4. Next morning I do a new commit, but when I go to Push/Pull in VS Oce on my local I get the error.

**What I should have done is after my merge in remote, I should Pull or Fetch Remote into my local before making further changes then I would not have gotten the error.**

**So my daily routine should change, when I merge Team into Dev on my remote I must also pull it to Local straight away**

I also had another compounding factor that my new commit clashed with what was merged into my Dev branch, so I received different error for that telling me to remove or stash my changes before I Pull.

So to round this out doing things in the right order might have prevented the error in the first place. (might have).

Answer (score 1):

This means that your local master and remote master have diverged, meaning they both have contributions that cannot be simply fast-forwared.
In order to keep your local commits you can follow these steps:

```
1. git switch -C feature_branch (from master, create local branch with your local commits)
2. git switch master
3. git reset --hard origin/master (lose all local changes, and become same as origin/master)
4. git switch feature_branch
5. git merge master (add remote changes to your local)
6. git push
7. Make a pull request for master.
```

Comment: This is essentially an extremely convoluted way of doing a pull.

Answer (score 1):

In my case my issues was tags, and below is the fix:

```
git pull --tags -f
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have changes in my local branch.

I only wanted to pull the latest changes from the remote server into my local branch.

So I deleted the 'unmerged' local branch (in the following example: `troublesome_branch`) and then switch to the remote version of it:

```
git checkout another_branch
git branch -D troublesome_branch
git checkout troublesome_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related to your problem, but note that there was a problem with the v2.34.0 version of Git. The `git pull` command haven't the behavior that is expected.

A message from the release note about the fix coming from Git and the new version from 2021-11-24:

> "git pull" with any strategy when the other side is behind us should
> succeed because it's a no-op, but doesn't".

*[Git v2.34.1 Release Notes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.34.1.txt?_sm_au_=iVVj782VRqn02nW5T0ctvK6QGqWFJ)*

Comment: It is still broken, and is being fixed for Git 2.34.2 or 2.35. See the [end of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64163084/6309).

Comment: It seems that you have actually worked on the subject more than I have. Ahah. However, I no longer have this concern of "Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
discouraged." since version 2.34.1 of Git.

Answer (score 0):

For me it, once I setup the config, still I was unable to merge.
It was giving fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting

None of the above solutions worked so I used merging with develop. merge origin/develop

Comment: This is what happens if you set the third option but no ff is available. In that case you might be able to solve it with `git pull --no-ff`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was pulling from a different branch when I intended to just get the latest update of the branch I want. I change back the branch, and it's back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting errors with `--ff-only`, so I just created a new branch that I synchronized with the remote one:

Jump on another branch:

```
git checkout -b other-branch
```

Change its name so it doesn't bother you:

```
git branch -m myBranch broken-myBranch
```

Checkout the remote branch you wish to sync:

```
git checkout origin/myBranch
```

Create a local branch for it:

```
git checkout -b myBranch
```

Attach the remote branch to yours:

```
--set-upstream-to=origin/myBranch myBranch
```

Answer (score 0):

Solving this issue is easier with some a tool having ui for git. I use IntelliJ for this. Here are the steps you need to follow:-

1. Checkout to the branch in which you want to merge your code (say master).
2. Take latest pull in master (git pull origin master).
3. Checkout to you branch (say test).
4. Right click in the editor -> go to Git -> Merge
5. Select master branch in the popup. Click on merge
6. Resolve conflicts (if any).
7. Run "git pull origin test" in your test branch
8. Run "git push origin test" in your test branch

Congratulations!!! You fixed the issue.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure the branch you're currently in exists in the remote repository. If you are working with Atlassian ([Bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket) and [Jira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jira_(software))) could be that after a pull request your branch got deleted and you forgot to check out to some other branch (i.e. master/develop).

Answer (score -5):

It's works for me.

```
git reset --hard origin/<remote_branch_name>
```

Comment: This not only doesn't answer the question, but is also DANGEROUS because you may lose your work.