# warning: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is discouraged

Tags: git

Can someone who knows git please give a simple and reasonably correct way of dealing with this output warning:

```
git pull
warning: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
commands sometime before your next pull:

  git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
  git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
  git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only

You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
invocation.

Already up-to-date.
```

There are 4 answers here:
[How to deal with this git warning? "Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is discouraged"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62653114/how-to-deal-with-this-git-warning-pulling-without-specifying-how-to-reconcile)
with a ton of explanations. I don't really care which of the 3 options I use as long as it's reasonable.

Can I have 1 answer with 1 recommended option please so I can get on with my life.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with this git warning? "Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is discouraged"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62653114/how-to-deal-with-this-git-warning-pulling-without-specifying-how-to-reconcile)

Comment: There is a reason why they made it a config option: each possible config may be "reasonable" in one scenario but not another. Only you can tell what is reasonable for you.

Answer (score 4):

*You* have to pick one.  The best one for you might not be the same as that for everyone else.  Personally I'd recommend `git config --global pull.ff only`—or my own preference, which is to *not use* `git pull`—and that's also the top recommendation in the accepted answer at the duplicate.  But it's really up to you; this is a lot like claims about which ice cream flavor is the best.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup><strike>Chocolate</strike> <strike>strawberry</strike> <strike>raspberry</strike>