# Why Git is throwing me a warning when trying to pull?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket repo which is managed by two developers. This is a Flutter project. initially I created this and pushed this to the remote repo. When there is an update, I try to do `git pull origin master`, and it gives the following warning.

```
hint: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
hint: discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
hint: commands sometime before your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
```

I know it advises me what to do, but what are the consequences of each step suggested?

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62653114/how-to-deal-with-this-git-warning-pulling-without-specifying-how-to-reconcile