# Git pull fails and asks me to do rebase. I've made no changes to the code

Tags: git, github

normally with git I'm making commits and push but I have project that I just want to monitor the tasks that have been done on daily basis and test them out in an emulator. So I'm not making any changes to any of the code.

This is what I do:

- `Git clone`
- run `yarn`
- run the emulator to test things out

the next day I want to check out what work has been done so I run `git pull` (again I have made zero changes) but I get an error message saying the following:

```
hint: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
hint: discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
hint: commands sometime before your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
```

I've never done `rebase` before and I don't want to mess anything up. What do I run to just pull all new changes so I can test them out? Sorry about the noob question as I'm still scared to run `git pull --no-rebase-`

Comment: It's possible, that some other developer did a rebase and forced push the changed commits. You should check if that was the case, because it changes what the best solution for you would be.

Comment: See the [answer by Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62653694/267) on a duplicate question.

Comment: This warning is relatively new. See the duplicate for discussion.