# VScode git sync is breaking due to git pull in git 2.29

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

With git 2.29 and greater there is this issue that comes with the git pull [How to deal with this git warning? "Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is discouraged"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62653114/how-to-deal-with-this-git-warning-pulling-without-specifying-how-to-reconcile)

However setting `git config --global pull.ff only` is still not solving the issue when you try to do a sync changes through vscode after you have made a commit so that your local branch is ahead of the remote branch. I keep getting the error `fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.`

[image]

Comment: I suspect the git plugin for vscode needs to be updated to handle this case. I assume configuring git pull to do a merge is not an option?

Comment: There's a bug in the `pull.ff only` setting code in Git 2.33 (perhaps it extends back to 2.29?), that will be fixed in Git 2.34. The existing bug creates a problem with VS. My solution is "don't use VS" but that doesn't work for most people... :-) Setting `pull.ff` to `true` will probably work around it (not tested since I don't use VS).

Comment: I can confirm that the issue is fixed with git 2.34

Comment: git config --global pull.rebase true

this solved for me @LasseV.Karlsen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is solved in git 2.34.