# How to Merge when you get error "Hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them."

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-pull

I'm working with 1 other developer who has created a branch that needs to be merged with master.

I get this error when attempting to Pull in Git in Visual Studio Community (not Visual Studio Code) to a Bitbucket repo

If I attempt to Push it says "unable to push because your local branch is behind the remote branch".

This is the error:

```
Hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
Hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
Hint: your next pull:
Hint: 
Hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge
Hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
Hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
Hint: 
Hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
Hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
Hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
Hint: invocation.
Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
```

I've found various things that discuss this, eg

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/git-pull-error-pulling-without-specifying-how-to-reconcile-divergent-branches-is-discouraged?page=1&replyId=773818

and
[How can I deal with this Git warning? "Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is discouraged"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62653114/how-can-i-deal-with-this-git-warning-pulling-without-specifying-how-to-reconci)

But none of them explain WHY this is happening and what the actions actually do.

How can I merge in what's in the other branch into master, why is this message coming up and what effect do all the suggestions in the hints have?

Thanks

Comment: The reason it is happening is that what happens in your sandbox when you merge, rebase or fast-forward is quite different, so Git won't make the decision for you as to which one is best for you. Your task, now, is to understand the different options, and pick which one you want to use by default with you run `git pull`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I deal with this Git warning? "Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is discouraged"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62653114/how-can-i-deal-with-this-git-warning-pulling-without-specifying-how-to-reconci)

Answer (score 284, accepted):

As is often the case with confusing stuff in Git, there's some history involved.

The first thing to know is that `git pull` does too much stuff.  Well, for some people (me), it does too much; others like that it does this much; but in fact, it does two jobs, each of which has its own separate Git command:

1. `git pull` runs `git fetch`.  Most, but not all, of the arguments you give *to* `git pull` are passed directly to `git fetch`.  So `git pull` means *run `git fetch`* and `git pull origin somebranch` means *run `git fetch origin somebranch`*.
2. Assuming the first step succeeds, `git pull` runs a second Git command.

The reason to have a step 2 at all is simple enough: `git fetch` *obtains new commits* from some other Git repository, stuffing those new commits into your own repository where you now have access to them.  But then it *stops*.  You *have access to* the new commits, but *nothing is actually using* the new commits yet.  To *use* the new commits, you need a second step.

Initially, that second step was always `git merge`.  The `git merge` command is pretty big and complicated but it has a meaning that's pretty simple to describe: ***Merge* means *combine work*.**  Git will attempt to take work you have done, if you have done any, and work they have done, if they have done any, and combine the work, using simple and stupid automated rules.  These rules have no clue as to how or why you did the work, or what anything you changed *means*.  They just work based on "lines" in diffs.

There are, however, four possibilities here:

- Perhaps you did no work and they did no work.  You got no new commits.  There's literally nothing to do, and `git merge` does nothing.
- Perhaps you did some work and they did nothing; you got no new commits; there's nothing to do and `git merge` does nothing again.
- Perhaps you did no work and they did do some work.  You got some new commits.  Combining your lack-of-work with their actual work is easy and `git merge` will take a shortcut if you allow it.
- Perhaps you and they both did work.  You have new commits *and* you got new commits from them, and `git merge` has to use its simple-and-stupid rules to combine the work.  Git cannot take any shortcuts here and you will get a full-blown merge.

The shortcut that Git *may* be able to take is to simply check out their latest commit while dragging your branch name forward.  The `git merge` command calls this a *fast-forward merge*, although there's no actual *merging* involved.  This kind of not-really-a-merge is trivial, and normally extremely safe: the only thing that *can* go wrong is if their latest commit doesn't actually function properly.  (In that case, you can go back to the older version that does.)  So a "fast forward" merge is particularly friendly: there's no complicated line-by-line merging rules that can go awry.  Many people like this kind of "merge".

Sometimes the shortcut is not possible, and sometimes some people don't *want* Git to take the shortcut (for reasons we won't cover here to keep this answer short, or short for me anyway).  There is a way to tell `git merge` *do not take the shortcut, even if you can*.

So, for `git merge` alone, that gives us three possibilities:

- nothing to do (and `git merge` is always willing to do nothing);
- fast-forward is possible, but maybe Git shouldn't do it; and
- fast-forward is not possible, which means this merge isn't trivial.

The `git merge` command has options to tell it what to do in all but the "nothing to do" case:

- (no flags): do a fast-forward if possible, and if not, attempt a real merge.
- `--ff-only`: do a fast-forward if that's possible.  If not, give an error stating that fast-forward is not possible; do not attempt a merge.
- `--no-ff`: even if a fast-forward is possible, don't use the shortcut: attempt a full merge in every case (except of course the "nothing to do" case).

The `git pull` command accepts all of these flags and will pass them on to `git merge`, should you choose to have `git pull` run `git merge` as its step 2.

#### But wait, there's more

Not everyone wants Git to do merges.  Suppose you have made one or two new commits, which we'll call `I` and `J`, and your `git fetch` from `origin` brings in two new commits that *they* made since you started, which we will call `K` and `L`.  That gives you a set of commits that, if you were to draw them, might look like this:

```
          I--J   <-- your-branch
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/main
```

You can *fast-forward* your `main` to match their `origin/main`:

```
          I--J   <-- your-branch
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- main, origin/main
```

And, whether or not you do that, you can *merge* your commit `J` with their commit `L` to produce a new *merge commit* `M`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- origin/main
```

But some people prefer to *rebase* their commits—in this case `I` and `J`—so that they come *after* commit `L`, so that the picture now looks like this:

```
          I--J   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- origin/main
               \
                I'-J'  <-- your-branch
```

Here, we have *copied* commits `I` and `J` to new-and-improved commits `I'` and `J'`.  These commits make the same *changes* to `L` that `I-J` made to `H`, but these commits have different big-ugly-hash-IDs and look like you made them *after* the `origin` guys made their `K-L` commits.

The `git pull` command can do this kind of rebasing:

```
git switch your-branch
git pull --rebase origin main
```

does this all in one shot, by running `git fetch` to get their commits, then running `git rebase` with the right arguments to make Git copy `I-J` to `I'-J'` as shown above.  Once the rebase is done—remember that, like `git merge`, it may have merge conflicts that you have to solve first—Git will move the branch name `your-branch` to select the last copied commit: `J'` in this example.

Not very long after `git pull` was written, this `--rebase` was added to it.  And since many people want this sort of thing to happen *automatically*, `git pull` gained the ability to *default* to using `--rebase`.  You configured your branch to do this (by setting `branch.branch.rebase` to `true`) and `git pull` would do a rebase for you.  (Note that the commit on which your rebase occurs now depends on two things: the *upstream* setting of the branch, and some of the arguments you can pass to `git pull`.  I've kept things explicit in this example so that we do not have to worry about smaller details, but in practice, you do.)

#### This brings us to 2006 or 2008 or so

At this point in Git's development, we have:

- `git fetch`: obtains new commits from somewhere else (an "upstream" or `origin` repository for instance), often updating `origin/*` style remote-tracking names;
- `git merge`: does nothing, or a fast-forward, or a true merge, of some specified commit or the branch's upstream;
- `git rebase`: copies some set of existing commits to new-and-improved commits, using a specified commit or the branch's upstream, then abandons the original commits in favor of the copies; and
- `git pull`: using the branch's upstream or explicit arguments, run `git fetch` and then run either `git merge` or `git rebase`.

Because `git merge` can take `--ff-only` or `--no-ff` arguments, `git pull` must be able to pass these to `git merge` *if* we're using `git merge`.

As time goes on, more options start appearing, such as auto-stashing, rebase's "fork point", and so on.  Also, it turns out that many people *want* rebasing to be *their default* for `git pull`, so Git acquires a new configuration option, `branch.autoSetupRebase`.  When set to `remote` or `always`, this does what many of these folks want (though there are actually four settings today; I don't remember if it had four back then and have not bothered to check).

#### Time continues marching on and we reach the 2020s

By now—some time between 2020 and 2022—it has become clear that `git pull` does the *wrong thing* for many, maybe even most, people who are new to Git.  My personal recommendation has been to *avoid* `git pull`.  Just don't use it: run `git fetch` first, then look at what `git fetch` said.  Then, if `git fetch` did a lot, maybe use `git log` next.  And *then*, once you're sure whether you want `git merge` with whatever options, or `git rebase` also with whatever options, *run that command*.  **If you use this option, you are in full control.  You dictate what happens, rather than getting some surprise from Git.**  I like this option: it's simple!  You do need to run at least two commands, of course.  But you *get to* run additional commands *between* those two, and that can be useful.

Still, if a `git pull` brings in new commits that *can* be merged under `git merge --ff-only`, that often turns out to be what I want: do that fast-forward, or else stop and let me look around and decide whether I want a rebase, a merge, or whatever else I might want.<sup>1</sup>  And that often turns out to be what others want as well, and now `git pull`, run with no arguments at all, can be told to do that directly:

```
git config --global pull.ff only
```

achieves this.

Meanwhile, the other two `git config --global` commands in the hint you show in your question make the second command be merge or rebase.  So *now*, in 2022, it's easy to tell `git pull` to do what *I* would want it to do.  Furthermore, it seems that the Git maintainers have come around to my point of view: that `git pull` *without* some forethought is *bad*, and newbies should not use it.  So they've set up `git pull` so that it now *requires* that you pick one of these three options, if you want to run it with no arguments.<sup>2</sup>

So, you need to pick one.  **The *old* default *was* `git config pull.rebase false`, but that was a bad default.  I do not recommend it.  I *do* recommend `git config pull.ff only`** (though I still don't actually use it due to 15+ years of habits).

---

<sup>1</sup>One real-world example: I encounter some bug that's a problem for me.  I make a change to the code that I know is wrong, but lets *me* get *my* work done.  I commit this horrible hack.  I then wait for the upstream to make changes.  They do and I bring in the new commits.  If they've *fixed* the bug, I want to *drop* my fix, not merge or rebase it.  If they *have not* fixed the bug, I want to rebase my hack (which may or may not need some tweaking).  The "have they fixed the bug" test requires something `git pull` cannot test on its own.

<sup>2</sup>Note that running `git pull` *with* arguments is not supposed to generate this kind of complaint.  I still don't run it much, so I'm not quite sure what the bug was, but in the first round or two of implementation of the new feature, there was a bug where `git pull` would complain inappropriately.  I believe it is fixed in 2.35 and am almost positive it's fixed in 2.36, which should be out any time now.

Comment: You had a lot to say about it, and you clearly know more than me on this topic. But I'm still left wondering why Visual Studio isn't configured by default to work and merge changes (I thought that was what versioning software did.) And I personally am not using a command line. I'm just using the IDE. Does this mean Microsoft created versioning control within VS that is just unusable?

Comment: @JonathanWood: I haven't used VS, but I know people who have used it for many years: it predates Git, or at least has versions that were never intended to work with (and did not work with) Git. So its Git interface had to be bolted on later, and that's a recipe for problems. Git's approach to version control is unusual (as compared to most other VCSes), so anyone thinking along conventional lines back in the day when Visual Studio was conceived would not have anticipated the kinds of curves Git would throw at you.

Comment: what do you mean " simply check out their latest commit while dragging your branch name forward" ?

Comment: @CatherineIvanova: A *branch name*, in Git, points to a single commit (see the drawings above in the "but wait, there's more" section). We run `git checkout <name>` or `git switch <name>` and we get the commit to which the name points. But now look at the first and second drawings: in the first one, `main` points to `H`, and in the second, `main` points to `L` just like `origin/main`. How do we make the first *become* the second? The way Git does it is to check out the *commit* `L` (as found via name `origin/main`), then make the *name* `main` point to `L`.

Comment: Meanwhile, commit `L` is *forward from* `H`: we move right-and-down from `H` to `K`, then right-only from `K` to `L`. So the name `main` simply "moved forward", or was "dragged forward", by this particular operation. It's a checkout-and-move-name operation, and Git calls this a "fast forward merge" even though there's no actual *merging*.

Comment: It's easy to provide confusing explanations of simple stuff that git does all the time.  There are lots of explanations like that on the web.  (Some of them are in the official git docs.)  This is not that.  This is a great answer.

Comment: Mercurial advocates say this all the time. I never knew why. Then I ditched my laptop for a desktop at work and one at home. Now I do work in two places, I realise, YES, you gotta fetch then merge. Thanks heaps for this answer.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer. While I myself have answered similar question in an [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62653400/10625611), I would rather people read this to get a much better clarity on the topic. Will add a reference to this post. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "shortcut"?

Comment: Well structured answer, it took me a very short time to understand the problem and what I had to do (first pull, then merge with my preferred strategy), now I will save it for later study :)

Comment: What a wonderful answer.  Taking the time to explain the four possibilities (who made changes -- you, them, neither, or both) and then link those to the git options made it all clear to me in a way that no amount of prior reading had, plus the diagrams are excellent.

Comment: This a pleasure to read.  I've come back to it multiple times and each time learn something new.  I wish I could upvote multiple times because it has been useful multiple times!

Comment: This is a great explanation, but I'm a bit confused still - maybe our process is different. If a coworker makes commits on main that I want to pull in, and I'm working on my-branch, I would checkout main, run git pull, then checkout my-branch and merge in main. My local copy of main should never be ahead of the origin, so I don't see any danger there, and if they fixed the same bug I did, this would just yield a conflict during the merge that I'd then resolve. Am I just using a non-standard or different workflow than what's being described here?

Answer (score 63):

I had this issue using Visual Studio - the following command solved it for me

```
   git config pull.rebase false
```

Comment: where did you run that command?

Comment: worked for me thanks. :)
@ChrisHDog in terminal

Comment: hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge

Comment: Its works good.

Comment: What does it do though?

Comment: @Nike - The academic dissertation above can provide everything you need to know about this issue

Comment: @JGilmartin have you read it?

Comment: what an awful answer, I can't believe it's got so many votes!

Comment: @charliefortune - i know, a simple single command that solves the problem - horrendous

Answer (score 36):

Running `git fetch && git merge` usually works for me.

Comment: Spent quite a lot of time trying to figure out before read your suggestion. It worked perfectly for me too! Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me as well. 

I had a develop branch and I wanted to update it with master branch code so from develop branch I used - git fetch && git merge origin master. 

Now I just have to resolve the conflicts.

Comment: I recommend `git fetch` followed by `git merge` rather than trying to combine the two, since the original issue is caused by running `git pull` which is a combination of these two.

Comment: only `git fetch` did the work for me

Comment: Life Saver. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me as well in 2024.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same issue. What solved it for me is the running the following line of codes:

```
git config pull.rebase false
git pull
git commit -m "my commit message"
git push
```

Then, to check if everything is now working, run "git status" again.

Answer (score 5):

I ran to this problem and fixed using `git merge origin/main main` where main is a target branch.

Comment: It fixed the warnings and merged

Comment: failing to udnerstand what i did, did it just override the rebase and did git merge?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. In my case, after getting the 'divergent branches' error, I followed these steps to pull remote develop branch to my local feature branch using the merge strategy:

1. In your local feature branch (feature/serdar-dev), execute `git pull origin develop --no-rebase;`
2. When the merge message screen appears (similar to "Merge branch 'develop' into feature/serdar-dev") in Vim to save and exit without any changes, press `Esc`, then type `:wq`, and press `Enter`.
3. Execute `git push --set-upstream origin feature/serdar-dev;`

Now you can see the "Merge ..." commit in your remote branch.

###### Referance

- [Git Docs: git pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)